# Using spade lugs to terminate wires under screw posts

Tags: wiring

I was wondering if it would be advantageous (electrically) and acceptable (code-wise) to use spade lugs as wire terminations under receptacles with screw posts. Instead of using a typical side-wire connection, which is often difficult with stranded wire, such as 8AWG to a weatherproof metal box, can the wire be terminated with a spade lug, sized for the wire, then the lug screwed down instead?

I imagine something like this:

[image: Spade Lug Connection]

Comment: Stranded wire shouldn't be wound around screws. I'm not sure about code, though. Seems like standard and appropriate use case.

Comment: @isherwood Would you like to post this as an answer?

Comment: Since I can only address half your question I'll leave it to someone more knowledgeable.

Answer (score 1):

I find on stranded thhn if you strip the wire back but not enough to remove the jacket completely off the copper it keeps the strands twisted and protects the ends of the wire. Clip some of it back if it is sticking far off the receptacle but not enough to bring the copper back to the surface. Not sure if I described it good enough but off you can picture it, it helps greatly on screw terminals if you have to loop your wire, plus I don't trust crimp on connections, they fail often in my opinion

[image: Here's a picture]

Comment: Crimps failing is typically due to improper crimping...

Comment: I understand how to make a proper crimp connection, so that's not the issue. When used correctly, they tend to work very well (as is often the case).